# Кусок кода из jQuery в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой код на jQuery:

```
names = [];
$('#list a').each( function (key, val) {
    names.push($(val).text());
});
```

Каким будет аналог на классическом JavaScript?
Спасибо!

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, а зачем? jQuery стал слишком тяжелым для вашего проекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы написать аналог, нужно предварительно определить - что именно происходит в данном куске кода:

1. `$('#list a')` - выбираются в `<a>` внутри элемента с `id="list"`
2. `.each( function (key, val) {...})` - идет цикл по выбранным элементам
3. `names.push($(val).text());` текст из проверяемого элемента заносится в массив

---

Каждому из этих действий можно найти соответствие:

1. [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - для выборки
2. любой цикл: [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) и т.д.
3. [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) - для получения содержимого элемента.

---

Пример:

```
var names = [];
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#list a'), function (val, index) {
    names.push(val.textContent);
});
```

Также, как можно заметить, тут идет перевод из одной коллекции в другую, для такой операции отлично подходит [метод `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var names = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#list a'), function(el){
    return el.textContent;
})
```

Comment: Только вот можно ли считать код с `querySelectorAll` - классическим JavaScript'ом? Если уж по классике, то `getElementById` и т.д.

Comment: @Astronavigator, конечно можно - это стандартный механизм, для него не нужно дополнительных библиотек

Comment: "стандартный" - это еще не значит "классический" :). Насколько я понимаю, эта функция довольно новая. Хотя, может быть, теперь любой JavaScript называют классическим....

Comment: @Astronavigator, классический - это без использования библиотек

Comment: @Astronavigator, `getElementById` - это не классика, это ретро :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
// JQuery
names = [];
$('#list a').each( function (key, val) {
    names.push($(val).text());
});


// pure JS
names2 = [];
document.querySelectorAll('#list a').forEach(function (key, val) {  
  names2.push(key.textContent);
});


console.log('names:' + names);
console.log('names2:' + names2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="1">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">test2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

где

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - возвращает список элементов в пределах документа (поиск осуществляется в пределах указанного элемента) которые соответствуют указанной группе селекторов. Возвращает объект типа NodeList.

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - выполняет указанную функцию один раз для каждого элемента в массиве.

Comment: а я вперед :-P и еще и с объяснением :-)

Comment: @Grundy умница дочка %)